# In SQL Server can I index on an "AS" column?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kanji] 
(
    [KanjiId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [Freq] INT NULL,
    [Grade] INT NULL,
    [Hash] AS (CONVERT([bigint], hashbytes('md5', [Name])) % (5) + (5)),
}
```

I would like to index by `Text` and then `Hash`. But is it possible with a column that is computed with an `AS` expression? And if so are there performance issues I should consider?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns

Comment: Did you *try*? If so, did it succeed or return an error message? That would seem a quicker approach than asking random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `Name` column in your table, so your formula to create the `Hash` files...

Assuming you meant to take a hash of `Text`, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kanji] 
(
    [KanjiId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [Freq] INT NULL,
    [Grade] INT NULL,
    [Hash] AS (CONVERT([bigint], hashbytes('md5', [Text]) % (5) + (5))) PERSISTED
)
```

By adding the `PERSISTED` keyword to the computation formula, you're actually storing those computed values *on disk*, with the table row, as if it were a "normal" column. With this, you can **definitely** add an index on `(Text, Hash)` to your table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix01_Kanji ON dbo.Kanji([Text], [Hash])
```

Comment: If I didn't mention persisted on Computed Column and also I create Index for that computed column, at that time whether the optimizer will use index on that computed column or not?

Comment: @RGS: not sure if you can even *create* an index on a computed column that is not persisted..... check out [the MSDN documentation on how to create indexes on computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns) - does that help you?

Comment: It helped me lot to understand creating index on computed column in SQL Server.